# Access a remote mongodb server

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, remote-access

I have a ubuntu remote machine which I access using ssh and I have installed mongodb on it, and I wish to access it remotely using the uri of the mongodb which is

`mongodb://<machine_ip_address>:27017/<database_name>`

I have also tried to change the /etc/mongod.conf and the edited file is this:

```
systemLog:
      destination: file
      path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
      logAppend: true
  storage:
      journal:
          enabled: true
  processManagement:
      fork: true
  net:
      bindIp: 127.0.0.1,my_ip
      port: 27017
  setParameter:
      enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

Is there a way I can give my local machine access to the remote server db by entering the uri of the remote server mongodb in my spring boot application?

Comment: Do you have a firewall in between? Is port 27017 open?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit   I have adjusted the firewall for my IP and give the access of my IP in the port 27017 by making change in the /etc/mongod.conf

Comment: so i think you probably already do this thing, but do you restart mongo server after changing config file?

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi yes